# Валидация даты на PHP. Как лучше реализовать?

Tags: php, дата

Есть дата в формате YYYY-MM-DD. Столкнулся с проблемой проверки ее достоверности. Первое, что пришло на ум, это регулярные выражения, как-то так...

```
if (preg_match("/([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))/", $date)) {
...
```

...но здесь, насколько я понимаю, не учитывается тот факт, что в месяцах разное колличество дней, да и про высокосный год тоже забыли.

Как это лучше всего реализовать?

Comment: `^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$`

Comment: Благодарю! Буду пробовать!

Comment: Это dd/-.mm/-.yyyy, если что. Надо порядок поменять, если будете использовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, вроде, нашел вариант:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d') {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}

var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-03', 'Y-m-d'));
```

Даже checkdate() не понадобилась :)

Comment: Такой код вроде должен отработать корректно при 20-20-2020

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы получить при таком раскладе false?

Comment: А такой возможности нет). Выше в комментарии вам регулярку предложили - только так насколько знаю.

Comment: Да, я заметил. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Хотя погодите, внимательно код посмотрел), и ваш код работает http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cd7faa7ca7aeccac4e4122377b867f0cba52f671

Comment: Это меня радует! :) Хорошего дня!

Comment: Хорошее решение) -> добавил в копилку знаний